# Nesting ion-nav-view inside nav-view

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

So folks, i was trying to have a template inside ion-nav-view but the state does not recognize it. 
I wanted to have like

```
<ion-nav-view>
   <ion-nav-view name="menuContent">
      <nav-view name="historyContent">
      </nav-view>
   </ion-nav-view
</ion-nav-view
```

here is the state code
so view "menuContent" has the app.serviceHistory state
and inside view "menuContent" i wanted to have another view "service_table_view" which should be loaded in the same state of "menuContent" view i.e. "app.serviceHistory"

```
 .state('app.serviceHistory', {
      url: '/serviceHistory',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/serviceHistory.html',
          controller:'serviceHistoryCtrl'
        },
        'serviceView':{
          templateUrl:'templates/browse.html',
          controller:'serviceHistoryCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

It does not load the template browser.html, am i missing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys, trying to fiddle around the code, i found out that if i had to play around then  will load the template inside the "menuContent" view. However, i had to create a new state in order to achieve that which looks like this

```
  .state('app.serviceHistory', {
      url: '/serviceHistory',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/serviceHistory.html',
          controller:'serviceHistoryCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
   .state('app.serviceHistory.singleHistory', {
      url: '/singleHistory',
      views: {
        'serviceView': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'

        }
      }
    })
```

The View

```
<ion-nav-view>
   <ion-nav-view name="menuContent">

      <ui-view name="historyContent">
      </ui-view>
   </ion-nav-view
</ion-nav-view
```

But, again, my target was to load two views inside a single state. I will try new things if it works.

Note that ion-nav-view inside ion-nav-view will hamper the css architecture so we should use "ui-view" i guess, which in my case is working in nested condition perfectly

Comment: and where is serviceView?